# Is there a downloadable document available that encapsulates the core rules enforced by StyleCop?

Tags: c#, coding-style, stylecop

Is there a downloadable document available that encapsulates the core rules enforced by StyleCop?

We've settled on C#, and we're going to be using FxCop and StyleCop to enforce design and style guidelines. To help get folks ramped up to speed, we'd like to make sure they have printed versions of the reference materials on hand as *casual reading material,* so I was hoping that there were PDF versions of the rules references around.

My searches so far for the StyleCop rules reference have been fruitless. If anyone knows if these rules are available as a consolidated document (either as PDF, XPS, or some other single downloadable reference), I'd very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rule list is available as a [.chm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_help) file on codeplex: [StyleCop 4.3 Rules Documentation](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1425)